Polarizing more than one transistor using only one output of a comparator
I'm experiencing difficulties with designing and getting the circuit to function as intended. The comparator operates perfectly when paired with just one additional circuit, whether it's the blue LED, the green LED, or the timer. However, issues arise when I try to integrate all three components together.
The circuit I aim to create should function as follows:

When timer is off, the blue LED should light up while the green LED remains off.

When the timer is activated, the blue LED should turn off, and the green LED should turn on.


One more thing: the timer is triggered by joining TGR0 and TGR1. I tried reversing their positions on the transistor, and both appear to work normally. Is there an ideal position?


With some small changes, seems to work. Simulate it here.

I used a stiffer pull-up for the comparator, and I flipped the PNP the right way.
Not sure about your values for the timer, took a guess. Anyway, when COMP is high relay is energized; after COMP goes low the Darlington pair will keep the relay on until the 10uF cap is discharged.

The blue LED looks like it’s staying on all the time in the simulation.

Yes, that's an issue with the way the relay driver works: the Darlington base sinks current. If its base resistor is increased to 50k then the light goes out.

Below is the LTspice sim of a circuit with one MOSFET that I believe does what you want:


Your blue LED driver has the transistor upside-down so it will barely work, if at all.
An easy fix is to swap out the BJTs for MOSFETs:

simulate this circuit – Schematic created using CircuitLab

You have the BC327 wired upside down i.e. collector and emitter have become swapped: -

I mean it'll kind of work but not very well and the transistor could get destroyed on excessive reverse base-emitter voltage. I'm not saying that there are not other problems but this one sticks out a bit.
It'll also help if the 20 kΩ pull-up resistor was more like 1 kΩ. Make the base resistors more like 4.7 kΩ too.

Should I just swap GND and 12V, or should I also move the LED to the collector side?

I'd move the LED too.
